# Genericで定義したAがanyになる

Tags: typescript

mapみたいなのを定義したときに

```
class Foo {
    x: number = 1
}

class Bar<A> {
  constructor(public a: A) {}
  map<B>(f: (A) => B): Bar<B> {
    return new Bar(f(this.a))
  }
}

var bar = new Bar<Foo>(new Foo)

alert(bar.map(a => a.x).a) // 1
```

ここまではいいんですが、

```
alert(bar.map(a => a.fugaaaaaa).a) // undefined
```

本当はAってFooなので、持ってないfugaaaaの参照でコンパイルエラーになってほしいんですが...。

fで受け取ったAがanyになってしまいます...
何か対応策ありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. まずはコンパイラオプションで`noImplicitAny`を有効にしてみてください。
2. すると`map<B>()`メソッドの引数に渡す、アロー関数の引数`A`がエラーになります。

   - これは本来型パラメータ`A`を渡す意図かと思いますが、この表記では`A`という名前のただの`any`型の引数となってしまいます
3. `map<B>()`メソッドを以下のように書き換えてみてください。

```js
map<B>(f: (param:A) => B):Bar<B>{
    return new Bar(f(this.a))
}
```

4. すると期待するような以下のエラーが吐かれるようになるかとおもいます(tsc 1.6.2で確認済)。

`error TS2339: Property 'fugaaaaaa' does not exist on type 'Foo'.`